# Were there other marital relationships besides Anakin and Padme in the Jedi order?

Tags: star-wars

There is a vague idea that Obi-wan and Queen of Mandalore had a thing, but this isn't properly addressed in the Clone Wars series AFAIK.

But are there other instances of Jedi who go against the order for love/relationships?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't remember where, but (I think somewhere in the EU novels) I read that Corellian Jedi tended to ignore that particular requirement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Cereans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cerean) were exempt from the Jedi ban on marriage. We see in the prequels, for instance, a Cerean Jedi Master, [Ki Adi Mundi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi), who had five wives and seven children (though I don't believe his children or wives are ever on-screen).

The [Wookieepedia article on marriage](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Marriage) lists several other instances of Jedi marriages/romantic involvements:

- Shaela Nuur
- Ranik Solusar
- Nejaa Halcyon
- Jedi Masters T'ra Saa and Tholme fell in love, despite the vast difference in species, but ultimately did not get married.
- Master Obi-Wan Kenobi and Siri Tachi fell in love but this did not continue due to Tachi's demise.
- Kit Fisto and Aayla Secura had a long relationship until their deaths.

Comment: Five wives? You would HAVE to be a Jedi, to deal with five sets of in-laws!!!

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To using your lightsabre to carve the thanksgiving turkey probably makes people stop arguing for a bit

Answer (score 10):

*[Secrets of the Jedi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secrets_of_the_Jedi)* is a 2005 Star Wars novel by Jude Watson.

> The novel centers on the forbidden loves of certain Jedi characters.
>
> - In particular light is Jedi Knight Obi-Wan Kenobi's love for fellow female Jedi Siri Tachi.
> - The novel also makes a mention about the love existing between the Jedi Qui-Gon Jinn and the Jedi Knight Tahl, as well as the love and forbidden marriage between Anakin Skywalker and Senator Padmé Amidala.

---

As a note, this only applied to pre-ABY Jedi of Old Republic.

In New Jedi Order, Jedi could marry; matter of fact:

> Luke Skywalker married Mara Jade in the last book prior to Vong invasion

Comment: Kyle Katarn and Jan Ors, also during the New Jedi Order, fell in love and made no secret about it, though I dunno if they officially tied the knot.

Comment: @KeithS - Since New Jedi Order didn't prohibit Jedi from marrying (Um... Luke Skywalker anyone?), it is most likely that the question scope pertains only to pre-Skywalker Jedi Order

Answer (score 6):

Also, [Jedi Master Ki-Adi-Mundi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi) was allowed to marry on his home planet Cerea, due to the low birth rate for Cerean males. He had five wives, and seven daughters.

Answer (score 0):

Mallie and Kento Marek. Starkiller's parents.

Answer (score -1):

In Bioware's MMO TOR, the Jedi Knight's companion Kira Carsen specifically mentions the Jedi Order's rules on Marriage.

[Video of Kira's Conversation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rJsnUV2sxU&t=7m13s)

Specifically she mentions that there have been previous instances of marriage with the Jedi Council's approval.

Comment: <3 Kira is my favourite companion

Answer (score -1):

I know Lucien Draay's parents were both members of the Jedi Order who fell in love and were married. I don't know if the Council knew, but I'm pretty sure their Masters and fellow Knights who they had trained with were okay with it. Nomi and Andur Sunrider fell in love, and were married too (Andur was a Jedi, but Nomi didn't start her training until after his death) but I don't know if they told anyone in the Order about their relationship. This is just in the Legends, not the original story. They might have been just a touch more lax with this rule in the Old Republic Era. Or maybe the council would make a few rare exceptions if they trusted them enough. I've used *Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic* (comics) and Nomi Sunrider's Wookieepedia page as my sources of info.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you cite the sources for these?  Are they canon or legends?  The questions you add at the end are a bit extraneous; they might make interesting questions on their own, but they don't really belong in an answer.

Comment: @DavidW FWIW I think the questions are somewhat rhetoric.